# What is the procedure for reopening a deleted post?

Tags: support

This question specifically refers to a deleted post https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77037/receive-flysky-fs-i6x-radio-signals-directly-from-arduino-using-nrf24-lo1-radio

New information has come to light at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/514618/2-4ghz-radio-transmitter-and-receiver-circuits which may benefit the OP.

I am not sure if the post could be made "on topic", but the information could be useful to people that wish use the Arduino for a remote control subsystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second link you gave doesn't seem to relate to the Arduino. I suggest that the question be asked on [Drones and Model Aircraft Stack Exchange](https://drones.stackexchange.com/).

The question only peripherally involves the Arduino. If it were re-posted here (or undeleted) it would probably get short shrift. Sorry.

---

Having said that, if the original asker wanted to try, they could post a new question, making it clearer how the Arduino is involved. Bear in mind there are multiples models of Arduino. A more targetted question would do better.